# row_number or rank similar data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
col1    col2
A        A
A        A
A        F
B        B
B        B
B        H
C        L
A        A
A        A
A        A
A        E
C        C
C        C
C        C
C        C
C        C
C        J
```

And I want result like this:

```
col1     count
A         3
B         3
C         1
A         4
C         6
```

If the col1 <> col2 reset count... But I only want sql code not pl-sql etc.

Maybe row_number() over(RESET WHEN col1<>col2).

Please help me.

Ok freinds thank you. sorry for my bad english.

In fact my table like this :

```
id      col1    col2
1000     A        A
2000     A        A
3000     A        F
4000     B        B
5000     B        B
6000     B        H
7000     C        L
8000     A        A
9000     A        A
10000    A        A
11000    A        E
12000    C        C
13000    C        C
14000    C        C
15000    C        C
16000    C        C
17000    C        J
```

Id column is unique and has ordered values always. Maybe this will help us to solve problem. Sorry for my missing information to you. And I want solution like above.

I only want col1 and count. But not col1 unique, count must be 1,2,3 bla bla bla... until col1 <> col2...
After this row count must be reset.

Comment: You probably want to use the `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: how can I use group by ? If I use group by 'A' or 'C' will be unique.

Comment: Nevermind, I wasn't paying enough attention to the actual problem. Sorry.

Comment: Why is the first row in result A, 3, should it not be A, 2? I also agree with sgeddes that you need to have a defined ordering of the rows for this problem.

Comment: Never mind, I see now that that the row that violates the sequence should be included

Comment: Assuming the following sequense of tuples, what would be the result: (1,A,A),(2,A,B),(3,A,A)?

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  Unless you have a column that specifies the ordering, the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to note, that without having an `ORDER BY` clause, you cannot guarantee the order of the results.  To do this sort of calculation, it would be useful to have an identity (auto-incremental) field to establish an order.

That said, you can attempt to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create a field to order on.

```
with yourtablewithrn as (
  select col1, col2, row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn
  from yourtable
  ), 
yourtablegrouped as (
  select *,
    rn - row_number() over (partition by col1 order by rn) as grp
  from yourtablewithrn
)
select col1,
       count(col2) AS cnt
from yourtablegrouped
group by col1, grp
order by min(rn)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71c90/1)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above I agree with sgeddes that we need some kind of order that we can rely on for this kind of problem. row_number() over () wont do since it more or less is a random number:

```
create table yourtable
( n int
, col1 varchar(1)
, col2 varchar(1));

insert into yourtable values 
(1,'A','A'),
(2,'A','A'),
(3,'A','F'),
(4,'B','B'),
(5,'B','B'),
(6,'B','H'),
(7,'C','L'),
(8,'A','A'),
(9,'A','A'),
(10,'A','A'),
(11,'A','E'),
(12,'C','C'),
(13,'C','C'),
(14,'C','C'),
(15,'C','C'),
(16,'C','C'),
(17,'C','J');
```

For this sample data col2 has no impact. We could do (a slight variation of sgeddes solution):

```
select col1, count(1) 
from (
    select n, col1
         , col2
         , row_number() over (order by n)
         - row_number() over (partition by col1
                              order by n) as grp
    from yourtable
) t  
group by col1, grp
order by min(n)
```

But, what should the result be with a sample like below?

```
delete from yourtable;
insert into yourtable values 
    ('A','A'),
    ('A','A'),
    ('A','F'),
    ('A','A'),
    ('A','G');
```

Comment: nitpicking: the multi-value `insert` you used is not valid for Oracle

Comment: point taken, I did not notice that the fiddle where for sql-server.